# mongoose query not displaying in safari

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm getting data from mongoDB via mongoose, I'm using Angular and ng-repeat to loop on the data, it works fine on chrome but not on safari, I only get first value, why is that?

Here is my code:

router.js

```
router.get('/data', function(req, res, next) {
    PolyModel.find(null, function(err, poly) {
        res.json(poly);
    });
});
```

main.js

```
app.factory('Polys', ['$resource', function($resource){
    return $resource('/data', null, {
        'update': { method:'PUT' }
    });
}])
```

part of the Controller

```
app.controller("PolyController", function( $window, $scope, $resource, Polys, Machines ) {
    $scope.PolySections = Polys.query();
```

part of the template

```
element.poly(ng-class="classPicker(polySelected(PolySection.filters))" ng-repeat="PolySection in PolySections | orderBy: polyOrder" data-filter="{{PolySection.filters}}")
```

Comment: check if you are getting all the values in the controller. Do `console.log($scope.Polysections)` and tell us the result please.

Comment: I'm getting the proper array but I have new infos, I now know where the problem come from:

I have a JS function that starts on document ready, and I use nb = document.querySelectorAll( '.active-poly' ).length; $scope.sizer = nb; to get the size, on chrome I get the proper value when I log this but on safari it turns 0; I tested to put a static value and it works. My loop function is cast AFTER the length, how can it start without the value?

Comment: why do you need to find the length like this?

Comment: I'm looping on the ng-repeat elements to place every items in a bee nest pattern. I just found a way to make this work but this is not good practice at all I guess, I'm now using a settimeout 50 on the nb and start of loop, document ready seems to fire before ng-repeat has looped on Safari while it's the other way around on chrome.

Comment: why are you using document.ready??? Are you not using controllers in your angular app?

Comment: I do, its inside my PolyController, my angular.element(document).ready is only here to start looping after ng-repeat. It's shitty practice?

Comment: I don't think you need to keep it inside document.ready, also what does `$scope.sizer` represents???